# Jest mock the return value of an imported function

Tags: jestjs

Clearly, I'm misunderstanding something here regarding how jest works:
Code to be tested:

```js
const target = () => {
  if (filter()) () => 'hi';
}

const filter = () => false;

module.exports = {
  target, filter
}
```

In the code below, I would like `filter()` to evaluate to `true` so that when the code below calls `target`, `target` returns `hi`.  Is this possible? If so, how, and if not, how is this mocked/tested?

```js
const index = require('./index')
jest.mock('./index.js', () => {
 const o = jest.requireActual('./index.js')
 return {
   ...o,   filter: jest.fn(() => true)
 }
});

test('test', () => {
  const x = index.target();  
  console.log(index.filter())  // true
  console.log(x) // undefined ~ would like to see it return 'hi' instead
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mock is working.

In `target()` you are not returning anything, but the `() => 'hi'` is over-complicated.

```js
const target = () => {
  if (filter()) return 'hi';    // no need for a function here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in index.js, target function have to return value. See below code.

```
const target = () => {
  if (filter()) return () => 'hi'; //more exactly return (()=>"hi")()
  else return () => 'no'
}

const filter = () => false;

module.exports = {
  target, filter
}
```

And in test file, target function should be redefined.

```
    const index = require('./index')
    jest.mock('./index.js', () => {
     const o = jest.requireActual('./index.js')
     const filter = jest.fn(() => true)
     const target = jest.fn(()=>{
        if(filter()) return (()=>"hi")();
     })
     return {
       ...o,   
       filter,
       target
     }
    });
    
    test('test', () => {
      const x = index.target();  
      console.log(index.filter())  // true
      console.log(x) 
    });
```